# How to get rid of an unwanted scroll bar in a shiny app

Tags: shiny, scrollbar

Trying to finish my shiny app, I couldn't find a way to remove the scroll bar (the scroll bar isn't intended and I didn't actively choose it via code)
When I'm running the files individually I don't have the problem with the scroll bars. They only appear in the whole app.

Code for the whole app:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
ui = navbarPage("Cohen's D",
                theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),
                tabPanel("What's Cohen's D?",
                         withMathJax(includeMarkdown("about.Rmd"))),
                tabPanel("Calculate with statistics",
                                    source("CohenDplusVisual.r")[1]
                           ),
                tabPanel("Upload your data frame",
                                    source("CohenD_OwnDATA.r")[1]
                           ),
)

server = function(input, output) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)enter image description here
```

Again, if somebody could help me out, I would be extremely thankful[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7ktq.png)

Comment: To ask others to help you, it is best to provide a reproducible example. For example, what is in the `about.Rmd`, `CohenDplusVisual.r`, etc.  You want to provide code that others can run directly without any guessing.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide scrollbars for any `div` with the CSS overflow property. Here is a reproducible example for your `navbarPage` situation. Here we place it in an extra `tagList` so we can put the CSS somewhere (`navbarPage` does not have a style argument or another way to add extra CSS).

```
library(shiny)

ui <- tagList(
  tags$head(tags$style("body{overflow:hidden;}")),
  navbarPage(title = "Test page",
    tabPanel("Tab1", 
           tags$div(style = "height: 2000px; background-color:grey;"))
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session){}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```